# django CMS model migration

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I'm trying to write my own custom plugin. I've followed the tutorial on http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html and everything was alright. However when I add a field to model class I get an error:

```
no such column: testsite_hello.test_name
```

where 'test_name' is my new field. After that I run

```
makemigrations [appname]
migration [appname]
```

but nothing helps me. When I make a new fresh model with new fields everything goes fine. So I just need to refresh DB after changes in the model. How can I change the database after changes in the model?

Comment: Without seeing the exact commands and output, it's difficult to know what the problem might be precisely. It's possible that you are inadvertently running makemigrations on the wrong application for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django CMS model migration is just the same as any other kind of model.

First you create the migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

You should see the new migration being created, and should now find the migration file in the `migrations` directory of the application.

If you open the file, you should see that it contains references to the model/field affected by your changes.

Then you run the migration:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and Django should report that it has applied the migration.

That pretty much is the way to create/apply migrations.